# Trying to crawl council site with PHP - 'Invalid Checksum format'

Tags: php

Apologies in advance for the state of my PHP below. This is simply a hobby project that is driving me crazy.

I'm trying to crawl my local council site to retrieve what day my bins are to be collected.

```
<?php 
function curlResponseHeaderCallback($ch, $headerLine) {
    global $cookies;
    if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $headerLine, $cookie) == 1)
        $cookies[] = $cookie;
    return strlen($headerLine); // Needed by curl
}

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$cookies = Array();
$ch = curl_init('https://iweb.itouchvision.com/portal/f?p=customer:BIN_DAYS:::NO:RP:UID:625C791B4D9301137723E9095361401AE8C03934');
// Ask for the callback.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "curlResponseHeaderCallback");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$protected = get_string_between($result, 'id="pPageItemsProtected" value="', '"');
$arr = explode('set-cookie: ORA_WWV_APP_1030=', $cookies[0][0]);
$cookie = $arr[1];
$p_flow_id = get_string_between($result, 'name="p_flow_id" value="', '" id="pFlowId"');
$p_flow_step_id = get_string_between($result, 'name="p_flow_step_id" value="', '" id="pFlowStepId" ');
$p_instance = get_string_between($result, 'name="p_instance" value="', '" id="pInstance"');
$p_page_submission_id = get_string_between($result, '<input type="hidden" name="p_page_submission_id" value="', '" id="pPage');
$P0_PWD_POLICY_LONG = get_string_between($result, 'data-for="P0_PWD_POLICY_LONG" value="', '">');
$P0_PWD_POLICY_NO_SPACE = get_string_between($result, 'data-for="P0_PWD_POLICY_NO_SPACE" value="', '">');
$P0_PWD_POLICY_VALID_PUNCT = get_string_between($result, 'data-for="P0_PWD_POLICY_VALID_PUNCT" value="', '">');
$P0_PWD_POLICY_REPEAT_CHAR = get_string_between($result, 'data-for="P0_PWD_POLICY_REPEAT_CHAR" value="', '">');
$P0_PWD_POLICY_USERNAME = get_string_between($result, 'data-for="P0_PWD_POLICY_USERNAME" value="', '">');
$P0_PWD_POLICY_ALPHANUM = get_string_between($result, 'data-for="P0_PWD_POLICY_ALPHANUM" value="', '">');
$P153_CAL_MSG = get_string_between($result, 'data-for="P153_CAL_MSG" value="', '">');
$P153_ZABY = get_string_between($result, 'data-for="P153_ZABY" value="', '">');
$P153_USER_AGENT = get_string_between($result, 'data-for="P153_USER_AGENT" value="', '">');
$P153_SYSDATE = get_string_between($result, 'name="P153_SYSDATE" maxlength="" size="30" value="', '" autocomplete="off">');

echo 'p_flow_id' . $p_flow_id . ' </br> ';
echo 'p_flow_step_id' . $p_flow_step_id  . ' </br> ';
echo 'p_instance' . $p_instance . ' </br> ';
echo 'p_page_submission_id' . $p_page_submission_id . ' </br>';
echo 'cookie' . $cookie . '</br>';
echo '$protected' . $protected . '</br>';

$p_json = '{"salt":"'.$p_page_submission_id.'","pageItems":{"itemsToSubmit":[{"n":"P0_LANGUAGE","v":"EN"},{"n":"P0_PWD_POLICY_LONG","v":"","ck":"'.$P0_PWD_POLICY_LONG.'"},{"n":"P0_PWD_POLICY_NO_SPACE","v":"","ck":"'.$P0_PWD_POLICY_NO_SPACE.'"},{"n":"P0_PWD_POLICY_VALID_PUNCT","v":"","ck":"'.$P0_PWD_POLICY_VALID_PUNCT.'"},{"n":"P0_PWD_POLICY_REPEAT_CHAR","v":"","ck":"'.$P0_PWD_POLICY_REPEAT_CHAR.'"},{"n":"P0_PWD_POLICY_USERNAME","v":"","ck":"'.$P0_PWD_POLICY_USERNAME.'"},{"n":"P0_PWD_POLICY_ALPHANUM","v":"","ck":"'.$P0_PWD_POLICY_ALPHANUM.'"},{"n":"P153_POST_CODE","v":"ta1 1aa"},{"n":"P153_CAL_MSG","v":"","ck":"'.$P153_CAL_MSG.'"},{"n":"P153_ZABY","v":"","ck":"'.$P153_ZABY.'"},{"n":"P153_TEMP","v":""},{"n":"P153_USER_AGENT","v":"","ck":"'.$P153_USER_AGENT.'"},{"n":"P153_SYSDATE","v":"'.$P153_SYSDATE.'"}],"protected":"'.$protected.'","rowVersion":"","formRegionChecksums":[]}}';
echo $p_json;

$url = 'https://iweb.itouchvision.com/portal/wwv_flow.accept';
$data = array('p_json' => $p_json, 'p_flow_id' => $p_flow_id, 'p_flow_step_id' => $p_flow_step_id, 'p_instance' => $p_instance, 'p_page_submission_id' => $p_page_submission_id, 'p_request' => 'SEARCH', 'p_reload_on_submit' => 'A');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: ORA_WWV_APP_1030=" . $cookie));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
curl_close($ch);
```

Code explanation: I firstly go to the homepage (https://iweb.itouchvision.com/portal/f?p=customer:BIN_DAYS:::NO:RP:UID:625C791B4D9301137723E9095361401AE8C03934) which includes a form where I can enter my postcode. This form has a fair bit of security, all of the variables after the first curl_close are variables retrieved from the HTML which are used as 'Checksums' or 'Formkeys' for POSTing the form.

I then have a second CURL POST request which attempts to submit the form with all these variables.

The part that is driving me crazy is if I print all the variables to the screen and then add them to a POST tester e.g. Postman, then it works fine and the form is submitted. However if I left the PHP code run below I get a 'Checksum format error' returned by the council website.

I believe it relates to $protected variable. However I can validate its format is correct as if I print it to screen and then manually override my variable with the static text then it works fine.